# Woocommerce emails

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a Wordpress/Woocommerce site, using the 'woocommerce_email_attachments' to add pdfs to emails - a "new order" email to the shop and a "order processing" email to the customer.
It's working fine, except for this strange behaviour:
When I add the filter, it only sends one of the emails.
If I enable both in the settings, it only sends the "new order" one.
If I disable the "new order" one, the "order processing" email gets sent just fine.
Also, I can always resend the "order processing" mail from the Woocommerce backend.
If I disable the filter, both emails get sent just fine (but of course without the pdf).
Is there some logic to Woocommerce's sending of emails I'm not getting?
Or is it a resource problem?

Comment: Which plugin are you using for PDF ?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec: Not a plugin - the FPDF library.

Comment: I haven't never used this Library, so i can't tell you. But using **WooCommerce PDF Invoices & Packing Slips** plugin, i haven't any problems on the e-shops of my clients. So it might be a ressource issue.

Comment: Do you use, something like [**this snippet**](https://gist.github.com/lmartins/9234b5983b62e66fc87d)

Comment: Could you add to the question the complete code of your filter? and the add_action function?